# How to restrict insert specific number of rows in a table in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, database-trigger

How to restrict insert specific number of rows in a table in SQL Server?

I have developed a online course registration system for students where students reserve seats for their choice of courses.

Every course has sections, and each section has a limited seat capacity 30/35 or 40 which is defined in the `Section` table.

Problem is when students fight for last seat for same time then it exceeds seat capacity. So I have created a trigger on the table to handle number of rows entry according to seat capacity defined at section table.

That is working absolutely right. But for the trigger my web application becomes very slow. I do not want the trigger now. I need another duplicate solution to handle seat capacity exceed problem.

Can you please suggest a good solution without implementing a trigger?

My table structure and trigger is shown here:

[image: image for table and trigger]

Comment: Please post DDL for table and the trigger **as formatted text** - not a screenshot of it!

Comment: Simple trigger for checking row count & capacity should not be slow, assuming your tables have correct indexes.

Answer (score 0):

use stored procedure to insert data before inserting data check-in the index table and if rows are more return 1 as true and 0 as false and give a message in front 
Don't raise an error that takes more time to execute

```
IF (SELECT Count(p.rows) AS [Row Count]
    FROM sys.partitions p
    INNER JOIN sys.indexes i ON p.object_id = i.object_id
                             AND p.index_id = i.index_id
    WHERE i.type_desc = 'CLUSTERED'
    and p.object_id = object_id('table'))>40
Begin 
 insert into table 
 select 1 
end 
else 
 select 0
```

Comment: This is a broken solution by design, since it does not take into account concurrency. Rows may get inserted by another concurrently running call between the `IF` and the `INSERT`, which would in fact allow to exceed the number.

Comment: you can use TRANSACTION  that may help your problem

Comment: no it won't; even the most restrictive transaction isolation level `SERIALIZABLE` will not prevent this from happening.